# How to change image src after set by socket.io event?

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

Using socket.io, I'm pushing images from a server to the client using `base64` encoded strings:

```
socket.on('send_picture', function (data){
    socket_data = (socket_data + data);
    document.getElementById('imgid').src = socket_data
})
```

How can I reset the src of `'imgid'` at the next socket.io event? It works fine one time, but then won't display new images until I refresh the page

Comment: Are you using data URIs?

Comment: Yes, I am. It works fine after the first push from the server socket, but after that it appears the imgid.src URI is set, and won't change dynamically with a new value for "socket_data"

Comment: You can always work around it by just replacing the img object with a new one each time you want a new image to show.  That's what I have done in a slideshow because of problems with constantly changing the `.src` on one image.

Comment: How can I do that without refreshing the page?

Comment: Programmatically create a new image object with `var img = new Image()`, set its `.src` property, then insert it into the page by using [`.replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) to replace the old image object with the new one.

Comment: that seems to be the correct answer @jfriend why not add a proper answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that the most reliable way to load new image content is to create a new image element each time and replace the prior image object with the new one.  You could do that like this:

```
socket.on('send_picture', function (data){
    socket_data = socket_data + data;
    var oldImg = document.getElementById('imgid');
    var newImg = new Image();
    newImg.src = socket_data;
    newImg.id = 'imgid';
    oldImg.parentNode.replaceChild(newImg, oldImg);
});
```